# Preserve permission switch not working with cp?

Tags: permissions

Copying file from other user's directory with '-p' switch should reserve the permission as per the man page.

I am copying /etc/passwd to my home directory with -p switch but the permissions aren't preserved as follows:-

```
ijoin@stream:~$ ls -l /etc/passwd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1813 Sep 25 08:58 /etc/passwd
ijoin@stream:~$ cp --preserve /etc/passwd .
ijoin@stream:~$ ls -l passwd 
-rw-r--r-- 1 ijoin ijoin 1813 Sep 25 08:58 passwd
```

I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're logged in as `ijohn` and copying a file owned by `root`. `cp` command can not work around Linux's security machinery - your user is not allowed to create files owned by `root` or change ownersip of files to `root`. Doing so would be a security problem.

If you need to copy files owned by other users, do so using `sudo`:

```
sudo cp --preserve /etc/passwd
```

Here's a good explanation I found on [linuxquestions.org](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/why-doesnt-cp-p-file-copy-file-and-preserve-ownership-169007/):

> the -p argument works for all users in the constraint of that users
>   abilities on the system. generally non-root users will be able to
>   preserve ownership of their files that they own and are owned by a
>   group that the specific non-root user belongs to. they cannot preserve
>   ownership of files owned by other users (albeit, there may be ways
>   around this depending on the suid, guid, and sticky bits). root can
>   preserve the ownership of files owned by different users, because root
>   has full system priveledges. but joe_schmoe can not preserve the
>   ownership of files owned by root or files owned by billy, etc.
>   depending on where the file will be copied to, joe_schmoe can only
>   preserve file ownership of files owned by joe_schmoe and owned by a
>   group joe_schmoe belongs to.